# Moving image and text - Javascript + html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML page with some images and text, I have been asked to re develop it with only javascript. So far I have managed to flip the image and text from either side, put in new text and headings.

The problem I am having it that the images are skewed out of position and it looks wrong. How do I push the image in so that both the text and itself are in line.

HTML

```
<div class="article">
            <div id="myTills">
                <h3 id="headingTwo">About the Product</h3>
                <p id="paragraphTwo">
                    TigerTurf artificial chipping lawns and Golf Greens provide superior quality and ball roll. You can choose which type of synthetic grass you require for areas such as rough and tee boxes. Installing your practice green in your home Garden or business, will allow you to improve your game in your spare time. Your Golf Green will be smooth, durable and realistic to play on. If you have any more questions about design and installation, contact us anytime.
                </p>
            </div>
            <img id="pic4" src="images/nature-place-photo.png" alt="">
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
var x = document.getElementById("pic4");
x.setAttribute("src", "../images/water_image2.png");
x.style.cssFloat = 'left';
x.style.width = "356px";
x.style.height = "250px";

var y = document.getElementById("headingTwo");
y.innerText = "Tills"
y.style.textAlign = "left"; 

var x = document.getElementById("paragraphTwo");
x.innerText = "Contains new text"
x.style.textAlign = "left";

var y = document.getElementById("myTills");
y.style.cssFloat = "right";
```

Comment: why cant you use css

Comment: The subject is client side scripting, the whole point of it is that I use javascript

Comment: style `article` with `display:flex;` and it should put it's children inline.

Comment: @Erevald And what would the syntax for javascript look, I have tried as you said and I am getting uncaught error exceptions

Comment: @J.Gold add this to `article` `article.style.display = "flex"; `

Comment: @Erevald I cant do it that way but I understand what you mean, I have done it as such:

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("article");
    x.style.display = "flex";

I am getting an uncaught type error, it appears that "flex is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications on your code. In your HTML, I switched the position `img` and `#myTills` because the `display` of parent element is `table`. Since the `display` of parent element is `table`, you may want the display of `#myTills` to be `table-cell` so you can use `vertical-align: middle` to vertically center the alignment of the text.

HTML

```
<div class="article">
    <img id="pic4" src="images/nature-place-photo.png" alt="">
    <div id="myTills">
        <h3 id="headingTwo">About the Product</h3>
        <p id="paragraphTwo">
            TigerTurf artificial chipping lawns and Golf Greens provide superior quality and ball roll. You can choose which type of synthetic grass you require for areas such as rough and tee boxes. Installing your practice green in your home Garden or business, will allow you to improve your game in your spare time. Your Golf Green will be smooth, durable and realistic to play on. If you have any more questions about design and installation, contact us anytime.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var article = document.querySelector('.article');
article.style.display = 'table';

var x = document.getElementById("pic4");
x.style.width = "356px";
x.style.height = "250px";
x.style.display = "table-cell";

var y = document.getElementById("headingTwo");
y.innerText = "Tills"
y.style.textAlign = "left";

var x = document.getElementById("paragraphTwo");
x.innerText = "Contains new text"
x.style.textAlign = "left";

var y = document.getElementById("myTills");
y.style.display = "table-cell";
y.style.height = "250px";
y.style.width = "100%";
y.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
```

Is this what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I used as you said with a bit of padding and margin, worked a treat :) Thanks everyone!